# Rewrite code using generate statement (Verilog HDL)

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm trying to rewrite this code using generate statements (Verilog HDL):

```
integer j;
always@(posedge cpu_clk) begin
        // ACCU_RST
        if(RAM[3][7]) begin
            RAM[3][7] <= 1'b0;
            for(j = 10; j <= 15; j = j + 1)
                RAM[j] <= 8'b0;
        end
        
        // CPU write
        RAM[addr + 0] <= in_valid && cmd && (addr + 0 <= 9 || addr + 0 >= 16) ? data_in[8 * 0 + 7:8 * 0] : RAM[addr + 0];
        RAM[addr + 1] <= in_valid && cmd && (addr + 1 <= 9 || addr + 1 >= 16) ? data_in[8 * 1 + 7:8 * 1] : RAM[addr + 1];
        RAM[addr + 2] <= in_valid && cmd && (addr + 2 <= 9 || addr + 2 >= 16) ? data_in[8 * 2 + 7:8 * 2] : RAM[addr + 2];
        RAM[addr + 3] <= in_valid && cmd && (addr + 3 <= 9 || addr + 3 >= 16) ? data_in[8 * 3 + 7:8 * 3] : RAM[addr + 3];

        //CPU read
        out_valid <= !cmd && in_valid;
        out_data[8 * 0 + 7:8 * 0] <= !cmd && in_valid ? RAM[addr + 0] : out_data[8 * 0 + 7:8 * 0];
        out_data[8 * 1 + 7:8 * 1] <= !cmd && in_valid ? RAM[addr + 1] : out_data[8 * 1 + 7:8 * 1];
        out_data[8 * 2 + 7:8 * 2] <= !cmd && in_valid ? RAM[addr + 2] : out_data[8 * 2 + 7:8 * 2];
        out_data[8 * 3 + 7:8 * 3] <= !cmd && in_valid ? RAM[addr + 3] : out_data[8 * 3 + 7:8 * 3];
end
```

Yet I recieve the following errors if I try this:

```
// CPU write
    for(i = 0; i <= 3; i = i + 1) begin
        if(in_valid && cmd && (addr + i <= 9 || addr + i >= 16)) 
            RAM[addr + i] <=  data_in[8 * i + 7:8 * i];
    end
    //CPU read
    out_valid <= !cmd && in_valid;
    for(i = 0; i <= 3; i = i + 1) begin
        if(in_valid && !cmd) 
            out_data[8 * i + 7:8 * i] <=  RAM[addr + i];
    end
```

> ERROR: i is not a constant value.

(error points to data_in[8 * i + 7:8 * i] and out_data[8 * i + 7:8 * i])

Another try, using two always blocks, one for generate, one for ACCU_RST yields multiple drivers for RAM (duh).

Last try:

```
genvar i;
always@(posedge cpu_clk) begin
    if(ACCU_RST) begin
        RAM[3][7] <= 1'b0;
        for(j = 10; j <= 15; j = j + 1)
            RAM[j] <= 8'b0;
    end
    
    // CPU write cmd
    for(i = 0; i <= 3; i = i + 1) begin :CPU_W
        if(in_valid && cmd && (addr + i <= 9 || addr + i >= 16)) 
            RAM[addr + i] <=  data_in[8 * i + 7:8 * i];
    end

    //CPU read cmd
    out_valid <= !cmd && in_valid;
    for(i = 0; i <= 3; i = i + 1) begin :CPU_R
        if(in_valid && !cmd) 
            out_data[8 * i + 7:8 * i] <=  RAM[addr + i];
    end
end
```

That yields:

> ERROR: Procedural assignment to a non-register i is not permitted,
> left-hand side should be reg/integer/time/genvar

(and points to i = 0 and to i = i + 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you shouldn't use a generate block. The generate for loop must exist outside of an always block. And a values must only be assigned in one always block to be synthesizable. Take the below example, `RAM[2]` can be assigned when `addr==0` on the third loop (`i==2`), when `addr==1` on the second loop (`i==1`), and when `addr==2` on on the first loop (`i==0`). Three separate always blocks which is a synthesizable error.

```
genvar i;
generate
for(i=0; i<4; i++) begin
  always @(posedge clk)
    if (in_valid && cmd && (addr + i <= 9 || addr + i >= 16)) 
      RAM[addr + i] <=  data_in[8*i + 7 : 8*i];
end
endgenerate
```

Skip the generate and use a standard for loop inside the always block. Use indexed part-select (references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17779414/1959732) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18068296/1959732)):

```
integer i; // <-- not genvar
always @(posedge cpu_clk) begin
    /* ... your other code ... */

    // CPU write cmd
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1) begin :CPU_W
        if (in_valid && cmd && (addr + i <= 9 || addr + i >= 16)) 
            RAM[addr + i] <=  data_in[ 8*i +: 8];
    end

    //CPU read cmd
    out_valid <= !cmd && in_valid;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1) begin :CPU_R
        if (in_valid && !cmd)
            out_data[ 8*i +: 8] <=  RAM[addr + i];
    end
end
```