# Verilog : Muliplication of Integer and parameter and for loop

Tags: verilog

When i am trying to compile following verilog RTL cadence simulator is throwing a error as illegal operand for constant expression.

RTL is:

```
module selection_logic( data_out, data_in , valid_info);

input  [(number_of_channel * per_channel_data) - 1 : 0] data_in;
input  [number_of_channel - 1: 0] valid_info;

output reg [number_of_channel - 1 : 0] data_in;


integer i;

always @(*)
begin
for (i = 0; i < number_of_channel; i = i + 1)
begin
if (valid_info[i])
data_out[(per_channel_data*(i+1)) - 1: per_channel_data*i] = data_in[[(per_channel_data*(i+1)) - 1: per_channel_data*i] 

else
data_out[(per_channel_data*(i+1)) - 1: per_channel_data*i] = {per_channel_data{1'b0};
end
end


endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Array slicing using the `arrayName[MSB:LSB]` require MSB and LSB to be constants. Instead, use the `arrayName[start_bit +: WIDTH]`, where WIDTH is a constant and start_bit can be a variable. Refer to 
"[Indexing vectors and arrays with +:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18067571/1959732)" and "[What is `+:` and `-:`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17778418/1959732)"

```
data_out[per_channel_data*i +: per_channel_data] = data_in[per_channel_data*i +: per_channel_data];
```

If stuck with with Verilog-1995, then add a second for-loop and assign each bit individually:

```
for(i=0; i<per_channel_data; i=i+1) begin
  for(j=0; j<per_channel_data; j=j+1) begin
    if (valid_info[i])
      data_out[per_channel_data*i+j] = data_in[per_channel_data*i+j];
    else
      data_out[per_channel_data*i+j] = 1'b0;
  end
end
```