# Verilog - Why I can't declare multiple vars in a for statement?

Tags: for-loop, verilog, hdl

I have a code like this:

```
generate
genvar i, j, k;
for (i = 0, j = 8, k = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1, j = j + 8, k = k + 8)
    Register Register_inst (.d(w_data), .en(decoder_out[i]), .clk(clk), .q(trunc_32_to_n_bits(reg_out, j-1, k)));
endgenerate
```

Is it possible to have multiple vars in a for like in other languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of for-loops in Verilog, procedural for-loops (inside a `initial` or `always` block)and generate for-loops (outside of the `initial` and `always` block). Both are restricted to simple single variable assignments.

Typically you do not need multiple variables managed by a for-loop. In the majority of cases other values can be derived from one index. You code does not need three variables as everything can be determined from `i`:

```
generate
genvar i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1)
  Register Register_inst (.d(w_data), .en(decoder_out[i]), .clk(clk), .q(reg_out[i*8 +: 8));
endgenerate
```

For more on the `+:` array slicing operatior, refer to earlier answered questions:
[Indexing vectors and arrays with +:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18067571/1959732) and [What is `+:` and `-:`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17778418/1959732)

Note: SystemVerilog supports multiple variable assignments with procedural for-loops. There is still single variable assignment restriction with generate for-loops as per [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html).