# Is there a way to change range of cells in an array?

Tags: system-verilog

Given a matrix

```
logic [0:3] [0:3] matrix =
    {4'b 1111,
     4'b 1111,
     4'b 1111,
     4'b 1111
    }
```

During run time, I get input (x,y) as index.
I would like to reach indexes (x,y+1), (x,y), (x,y-1) and change them.

for example, if I get (x,y)=(1,2), then I would get

```
    {4'b 1111,
     4'b 1011,
     4'b 1011,
     4'b 1011
    }
```

I tried doing it in an always_ff block:

```
always_ff@(posedge clk or negedge resetN)
begin
     matrix[y-1:y+1][x] <= 0;
end
```

but it says range must be final index.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The *range* you are asking for is called a *slice* or *part-select* in SystemVerilog. There are two problems with what you are trying to do.

1. You can only slice the last the last dimension of a select. In other words, select must represent a contiguous set of bits. You are trying to do the reverse.
2. Selects must have constant widths. Assuming you fixed the first issue, you would have to do something like `[y-1 +:3]`. See [What is `+:` and `-:`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778418/what-is-and/17779414#17779414)

But it might be better just using a `for` loop.

```
always_ff@(posedge clk)
     for(yy=y-1;yy<y+2;y++) matrix[yy][x] <= 0;
```