# Shift n bits out of a register per clock

Tags: verilog, hdl, vivado

I am working in Vivado using Verilog. Assume I have 2 registers:

```
reg [3327:0]a;
reg [1023:0] b;
```

Each clock cycle Id like to take the 13 bits from a and 4 bits from b and multiply them.

> Clock 1:  a[12:0] * b[3:0]
>
> Clock 3: a[25:13] * b[7:4]

What is the most efficient way to iterate through these registers? Something tells me that using a for loop like this would not be correct?

Comment: I suppose I mean proper/least amount of resources? When I use a for loop it seems to want a constant in the reg[constant]. So using like reg[counter: counter-4] throws errors.

Comment: Ah, yes I had read about this and was unable to get the syntax correct, that link was useful! I think I understand now how it should be done. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score -1):

As noted by @toolic, Iterating using a loop is a fine way to do it and using the syntax found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778418/what-is-and)