# How to convert 1D data into 2D data?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a data of 1024 bit stored in `A` register.

```
reg [1023:0] A;
reg [7:0] B [0:127]
```

Now I want to convert it into 2 dimensional register `B`. How's it possible with minimum coding in Verilog?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a `for` loop:

```
module tb;

reg [1023:0] A;
reg [7:0] B [0:127];

always_comb begin
    for (int i=0; i<128; i++) begin
        B[i] = A[8*i +: 8];
    end
end

endmodule
```

[See also +:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778418/what-is-and)

Answer (score 1):

In System Verilog a streaming operator could be used for this:

```
module top;
  reg [1023:0] A;
  reg [7:0] B [0:127];
  always_comb begin
    B = {>>{A}};
    // this also works:
    //     {>>{B}} = A;
  end
  
  // testing
  initial begin
    for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
      A[i*8 +: 8] = i;
    
   #1 $finish;
  end
  always @* begin
    $display("A: %3d %3d %3d", A[7:0], A[15:8], A[1023:1016]);
    $display("B: %3d %3d %3d", B[127], B[126], B[0]);
  end
endmodule
```

Just note, due to the `B[0:127]` declaration, index `[0]` is the most significant one and maps to `A[1023:1016]`. If you want an opposite mapping, declare `B[127:0]`.